# Apex Conditional with custom number field leads to compile error

Tags: apex, custom-field

I created a custom field in my price book, `Tier_1_Limit__c`, which is a Number(10,0) field. I'm working with an extension to the Quote's standard controller and I simply want to compare the quantity value of a quote line item to the custom Tier 1 limit number field.  The Pricebook Entry field definition, Apex code, and corresponding compile error are shown below.

### **Field Definition**

[image]

### **Relevant Apex Code**

```
        QuoteLineItem[] items = [
            select 
                Product2.name, 
                Quantity,  
                ListPrice,
                PricebookEntry.Tier_1_Limit__c
            from QuoteLineItem 
            where quote.id = :quote.id order by Product2.name, ListPrice, Quantity];

        for(QuoteLineItem item : items){

            if (item.quantity <= PricebookEntry.Tier_1_Limit__c) {
                // do something here
            }
            ...
```

### **Error Message**

> Compile Error: Comparison arguments must be compatible types: Decimal,
>   Schema.SObjectField

---

What am I doing wrong here?  Please help if you can, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're treating `PricebookEntry` as a variable, but since it's a standard object name, it's a reserved string. Change your code to this:

```
for(QuoteLineItem item : items){

    if (item.quantity <= item.PricebookEntry.Tier_1_Limit__c) {
        // do something here
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb.  Thanks for catching my mistake!!!!